# Null check operator used on a null value - Flutter - FutureBuilder()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm currently creating a weather app using flutter, the weather data is coming from an API. It all worked fine but once I got back to the code it threw this error and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I know it is an issue with the "!" and "?" symbols but I'm new to Flutter and don't know how exactly to fix it. The error is thrown somewhere inside the **body: FutureBuilder(...)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weatherapp/services/weather_api_client.dart';
import 'package:weatherapp/views/additional_information.dart';
import 'package:weatherapp/views/current_weather.dart';
import 'package:weatherapp/model/weather_model.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

const API_KEY = "df2a3839ca0a3bfbd81de2c39e85cc77";

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  WeatherApiClient client = WeatherApiClient();
  Weather? data;
  IconData? weatherIcon;

  Future<void> getData() async {
    data = await client.getCurrentWeather("Berlin");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9F9F9),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 219, 219),
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: const Text(
            "Weather App",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu), // hamburger menu on the left
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              switch (data!.weatherIcon) {
                case "clear sky":
                  weatherIcon = Icons.wb_sunny_outlined;
                  break;
                case "few clouds":
                case "scattered clouds":
                case "broken clouds":
                  weatherIcon = Icons.wb_cloudy_outlined;
                  break;
                case "shower rain":
                case "rain":
                  weatherIcon = Icons.water_drop_outlined;
                  break;
                case "thunderstorm":
                  weatherIcon = Icons.bolt;
                  break;
                case "snow":
                  weatherIcon = Icons.ac_unit;
                  break;
                default:
                  weatherIcon = Icons.question_mark_outlined;
              }
              // display if we got data from api
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  currentWeather(Icons.wb_sunny_rounded, "${data!.temp}",
                      "${data!.cityName}"),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 60.0,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "Additional Information",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                        color: Color(0xdd212121),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const Divider(),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  // additional information Widget
                  additionalInformation("${data!.wind}", "${data!.humidity}",
                      "${data!.pressure}", "${data!.feels_like}")

                  // UI done, get actual info from API
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, as it seems to have been cut off in the copy-paste.

Comment: In lieu of that, the error in the title means that somewhere you used `!` on a variable that was null. You only use that operator when you know that a nullable variable is not null, i.e. `if (foo != null) { foo!.bar(); }`. You need to find the null variable and make sure you are verifying that it isn't null before marking it as non-nullable.

Comment: Perusing the code, my best guess would be that `client.getCurrentWeather(...)` is returning null. You should make liberal use of breakpoints and print statements to make sure that what you assume to be valid data is actually valid data.

Comment: `future: getData(),` Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: And also always use `if (snapshot.hasData) {...}` (which simply checks `snapshot.data` against  `null`) before you try to to access `data!`.

Comment: please Don't post your API keys in question cause they can be stolen and used by other people.

Comment: @JustaPerson Don't worry I changed it up before posting :D